# What is the complexity of the sorted() function?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have a list of lists and I am sorting them using the following

```
data=sorted(data, key=itemgetter(0))
```

Was wondering what is the runtime complexity of this python function?

Comment: The same as of a simple `sorted`.

Comment: `O(n log n)` like just about every other comparison sort used in a language library.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort

Comment: Timsort is a kind of adaptive sorting algorithm based on merge sort and insertion sort, then I thought it belongs to the comparison sort and no comparison sort can guarantee a time complexity smaller than lg(N!) ~ N log N.

Comment: @Yuushi Citation needed. Or do you just happen to know off the top of your head the complexity of `sort` in most of the major languages?

Comment: @mblakesley see, for example (PDF warning) [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f11/lectures/lect0913.pdf). Any comparison-based sort must take at least `O(n log n)`. Without knowledge of the data and a specialized sort to take advantage of that (e.g. radix sort), this is the bound. It's not much of a stretch to say that a general (comparison-based) sort in a standard library will have this complexity bound.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Provided `itemgetter(0)` is `O(1)` when used with `data`, the sort is `O(n log n)` both on average and in the worst case.

For more information on the sorting method used in Python, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort).

Comment: And if you know the complexity of `itemgetter(0)` and it's not `O(1)` then you can still work out the overall complexity: `sorted` makes `n` calls to `itemgetter(0)` plus what you say.

Comment: Doesn't Timsort have a best case of O(N).

Comment: @MC: It does. However, that's hardly relevant for practical use. Besides, *any* sorting algorithm can be made to have `O(n)` best case.

Comment: Relevant is also information, what is the best case. Here it is already sorted collection, which is good. So sorting already sorted array in Python should take O(n) time.

Answer (score 3):

sorted is like sort except that the first builds a new sorted list from an iterable while sort do sort in place. The main difference will be space complexity.

Answer (score 3):

It is the Timsort, and Timsort is a kind of adaptive sorting algorithm based on merge sort and insertion sort, then I thought it belongs to the comparison sort, and [it's said](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list), no comparison sort can guarantee a time complexity smaller than lg(N!) ~ N log N.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity in the average case would be `O(nlog(n))`