# Python `sorted()` time complexity with object of type `[tuples(int(), str())]`

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, big-o

What is the time complexity of this function that sorts words by their length in reverse order?
The function returns two lists: one contains sorted negative lengths, the other contains the sorted words.

```
def reverseSortedWords(words):
    ws = [(-len(w), w) for w in words]
    ws = sorted(ws)
    return zip(*ws)
```

I suspect a radix sort of O(n) here (because of the integers as first element of tuple on which the sort is performed), but this may as well be an O(n*log(n)) algorithm according to the most typical sorting algorithms and the fact that python uses a runtime interpreter.

Comment: what makes you think the runtime interpreter matters?

Comment: as here mentioned its O(nlogn) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434490/what-is-the-complexity-of-this-python-sort-method

Comment: The algorthim Python using for sorts it Timesort https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort