# How do i group points together within a range large space

Tags: python, numpy

I have 73,000 points with (x,y) coordinates in a space 2200x1700 I want to group all the (x,y) points together which fall in the circle with a radius of 35units.
To do this I have to run nested for loops having a time complexity of O(73000x73000) as i am computing the distance between each point and grouping the points whos computed distance is less than 35.

I need a optimized solution for this !

```
temp_cluster=cluster
for key,value in cluster.items():
    pointa=np.array((key[0],key[1]))
    for key2,value2 in temp_cluster.items():
        pointb=np.array((key2[0],key2[1]))
        distance=np.linalg.norm(pointa-pointb)
        if(distance<=35):
            cluster[(key[0],key[1])]=cluster[(key[0],key[1])]+1## here we are counting how many points lies within a radius of 35 for that particular point
```

Comment: When you are calculating the complexity, it is fine to say "it is in O(n*n)" instead of specifying n with 73000

Answer (score 2):

One optimization you can do is sort the points according to their `x` coordinates. Then for each point you need to consider just the points that have `x` coordinates within `35` difference of that point. With binary search you can find the points that are within this strip (i.e., find points `(x1, y1)` such that `abs(x-x1) <= 35)`. Roughly the steps are

```
sort(points) according to their x coordinates
for each point (x, y):
    count = 0
    start_index = starting index of points with x-x1 >= 35 (find using binary search)
    end_index = end index of point with x1-x<=35 (find using binary search)
    for each point(x1, y1) in (start_index, end_index):
        distance = calculate_distance(x, y, x1, y1)
        if distance <= 35:
            count = count + 1
    cluster[(x,y)] = count
```

Comment: Have you considered  the time complexity of the sorting step? Typically it's O(n**2).

Comment: I think sorting can be done in `O(n log n)` using Python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434490/what-is-the-complexity-of-this-python-sort-method