# What will be the time complexity of the following program

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Can anyone find the time complexity of the following python 3.6 program :

I **tried to find** and my **answer** is **O(N*n)**, where **N** is the range of the very first loop and **n** is the range of the **second for loop** which is **inside the first for loop**

This program is for https://www.codechef.com/FEB20B/problems/SNUG_FIT problem on **codechef**.

```
N=int(input())
for _ in range(N):
    S=0
    n=int(input())
    A=list(map(int, input().split()))[:n] #Assume amount of inputs to be strictly of n numbers
    B=list(map(int, input().split()))[:n]
    A.sort();A.reverse()
    B.sort();B.reverse()

    for i in range(0,len(A)): # Here range is n (same as len(A))
        if A[i]>=B[i]:
            S=S+B[i]
        else:
            S=S+A[i]
    print(S)
```

Comment: How did you get O(N*n) as your answer?

Comment: You are also forgetting the O(n) of sort which runes O(n log n) I believe.

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing how long the `input().split()` are (you explicitly cut them off at `n`, so presumably they're longer than that).

Comment: @HeapOverflow We also don't know how long `input()` will block for, I suppose.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh Which sorting algorithm does python list.sort() function use?

Comment: Not sure it makes sense to analyze the complexity of the whole thing - the outer loop merely repeats for T test cases. It is the inner algorithm after input has been taken that you would normally be interested in analyzing. Your loop to calculate `S` is O(n) and the [sort is O(n log n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434490/what-is-the-complexity-of-this-python-sort-method), so the complexity of the algorithm is O(n log n). In any case, does this algorithm solve the challenge?

Comment: `list.sort()` uses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pritam Banerjee wrote -

> `O(N( nlogn + n))` which effectively is `O(Nlog(n))`

**Actually it is not true**.

I am describing it more clearly along with the code.

```
N=int(input())
for _ in range(N):    # O(N)
    S=0
    n=int(input())
    # The following line is O(n)
    A=list(map(int, input().split()))[:n] #Assume amount of inputs to be strictly of n numbers
    # This line is also O(n)
    B=list(map(int, input().split()))[:n]
    A.sort();A.reverse()    # this is O(nlog(n))
    B.sort();B.reverse()    # this is also O(nlog(n))

    for i in range(0,len(A)): # Here range is n (same as len(A))  # this is O(n)
        if A[i]>=B[i]:
            S=S+B[i]
        else:
            S=S+A[i]
    print(S)
```

So overall `O(N( n + n + nlog(n) + nlog(n) + n)`

We can calculate in the following way -

```
  O(N( n + n + nlog(n) + nlog(n) + n)
= O(N( 3n + 2nlog(n))
= O(N (n + nlog(n)) (we can eliminate const number when determining complexity)
= O(N(nlog(n)) (as n > nlog(n), so we can eliminate the small part)
= O(N*nlog(n))
```

So overall complexity is `O(N*nlog(n)`, **not O(Nlog(n)**.

There are more difference between `O(N*nlog(n)` and `O(Nlog(n)`.

Hope this [post](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-calculate-time-complexity-of-a-program) will help you a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: This is clearly just a typo in Pritam Banerjee's answer; he wrote `O(Nnlog(n))` in the first sentence.

Comment: Yes got it. So it was his problem. He understood this when after my comment. Then why should I get negative? hilarious!

Comment: Your answer was probably downvoted because it is not useful to write a long explanation of why a typo is wrong. You could have just written a short comment on Pritam's answer pointing out the typo or proposed an edit fixing it. "It was his problem" is missing the point.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop is `O(N)` and inside that you sort `O(nlog(n))` so overall it becomes `O(Nnlog(n))`.

After that you have another for loop which runs `O(n)`.

Now the overall time complexity looks like this:

`O(N( nlogn + n))` which effectively is `O(Nnlog(n))`

Comment: I have understood your answer. But what would be the running time of the for loop which has the if else condition?

Comment: @Abhishek If else condition doesn’t have any effect on time complexity