# Which one is better in terms of Time and Space Complexity for checking wheter a string is anagram or not in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, anagram

Below are my implementations for the same:
1) Using Dictionary by keeping a count:

```
def anagram(s1,s2):
if len(s1)!=len(s2):
    return "No"
count={}
for let in s1:
    if let not in count:
        count[let]=1
    else:
        count[let]+=1
for let2 in s2:
    if let2 in count:
        count[let2]-=1
    else:
        count[let2]=1
for k in count:
    if count[k]!=0:
        return "No"
return "yes"
```

2) Using the built-in sorting function and comparing the strings:

```
def anagram2(s1,s2):
if len(s1)!=len(s2):
    return "no"
s1=str(sorted(s1))
s2=str(sorted(s2))
if s1.lower()==s2.lower():
    return "yes"
else:
    return "No"
```

3) Using the COunter from collections:

```
from collections import Counter
def anagram3(s1,s2):
    if len(s1)!=len(s2):
       return "no"
    s1=s1.lower()
    s2=s2.lower()
    if Counter(s1)==Counter(s2):
       return "Yes"
    else:
       return "no"
```

Which has a better time complexity among the two?
And are there any other approaches to make this anagram problem more efficient? if yes please let me know.

Comment: You can use `collections.Counter` for more efficiency.

Comment: Yes, indeed I forgot about that :)

Comment: Are you talking about computational efficiency or just raw speed?

Comment: Computational efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

There is no approach which is asymptotically more efficient than your first one, which runs `O(n)`. The second approach runs in `O(n log n)`.

The space complexity is `O(k)` with `k < n` for the first approach, with `k` being the number of unique elements, and `O(n)` for the second approach. Even considering the constant terms (which are generally omitted in asymptotic analysis), the first approach is more efficient since they both get a factor 2.

Within the class of `O(n)` algorithms, you could add some short-circuiting to improve the performances in some cases, and even write it into a single loop (which allows for some other short-circuiting at the expenses of some others), e.g.:

```
def is_anagram_1loop(a, b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        return False
    count = {}
    for x, y in zip(a, b):
        if x == y:  # short-circuit
            continue
        if x not in count:
            count[x] = 1
        else:
            count[x] += 1
        if y not in count:
            count[y] = 1  # cannot short-circuit here
        else:
            count[y] -= 1
    for item, num in count.items():
        if num:
            return False
    return True
```

```
def is_anagram_2loops(a, b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        return False
    count = {}
    for x in a:
        if x not in count:
            count[x] = 1
        else:
            count[x] += 1
    for y in b:
        if y not in count:
            # it should have beed found while looping through `a`
            return False
        else:
            count[y] -= 1
    for item, num in count.items():
        if num:
            return False
    return True
```

`is_anagram_2loops()` could have some more short-circuiting, e.g. it could quit as soon as `count[y]` is about to get negative, e.g.:

```
def is_anagram_2loops_b(a, b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        return False
    count = {}
    for x in a:
        if x not in count:
            count[x] = 1
        else:
            count[x] += 1
    for y in b:
        if y not in count:
            # it should have beed found while looping through `a`
            return False
        elif count[y] == 0:
            # it would get negative considering current `y`
            return False
        else:
            count[y] -= 1
    for item, num in count.items():
        if num:
            return False
    return True
```

---

However, speed-wise, using `collections.Counter()` is generally much faster since both loopings are done implicitly:

```
import collections


def is_anagram_counter(a, b):
    if len(a) == len(b):
        return collections.Counter(a) == collections.Counter(b)
    else:
        return False
```

The downside of the above could be the larger (roughly twice) memory consumption and that only the `len()`-based short-circuit could be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

First implementation is more efficient: it takes only `O(s1+s2)`. In second implementation you use `sorted` function, which is `O(nlogn)` (see this: [What is the complexity of this python sort method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434490/what-is-the-complexity-of-this-python-sort-method)) so total is `O(s1*log(s1)+s2*log(s2))`

Edit: And as someone else said in comments, `collections.Counter` is the easiest way:

```py
from collections import Counter
if Counter(s1) == Counter(s2):
     return "yes"
return "no"
```

(not sure if you want it case sensitive or not)

Comment: Case insensitivity?

Comment: if s1=god and s2=DOG; then this program will return No hence we may need to lower the strings so that there won't be any problem related to case-sensitivity!

Comment: as I said, it is not clear from your example if you want it to be case-sensitive or not. You can change it however you like

Answer (score 0):

The CPython implementation has byte code implementation of what can be calls to much faster underlying C-code. This complicates questions of "What is faster", big-O and complexity.
If it is really important then best to generate/aquire test data and *measure*.

For a general case I would first compare lengths which is quick, then sort the lowercased versions of each string and compare the result, (but only if lengths are the same). Sorting is done in a C routine internally with its own big-O and timing constants.

Something like:

```
def paddys(s1, s2):
    return len(s1) == len(s2) and sorted(s1.lower()) == sorted(s2.lower())
```

The `and` above is what is known as short-circuiting: If the fast len comparison fails then the whole expression returns False without going to the trouble of executing the sorts etc on the RHS.

Run all methods through your test data and measure their *actual* performance.

Comment: OP is after computational complexity, not raw speed.

Comment: My first comments on interpretaion v-s compiled C routines addresses this. Complexity is very hand waving if only the term with the highest "degree" is noted your actual data determines which term is most dominant due to constants. If there is an exponential term in an algorithm with a miniscule constant and a linear term with a large constant then it could be that for all practical data the algorithm appears linear when measured. Its complex. Best to measure, for your expected data.

Comment: No it is not hand waving. The reason to ignore "lowest degree" is the asymptotic behavior, which is a very well defined and concrete property of an algorithm. For **sufficiently large** inputs, it will **always** be the most important contribution. This is a theoretical questions, so all these "implementation details" are just that: implementation details. They may be crucial in the applications, but that is not really the scope of the question.

Comment: ...theoretical question...  ...sufficiently large inputs... ...implementation details... Work vs homework.

Comment: I am not sure what do you want to say with the last comment, it seems to be put in a gratuitously derogatory form. I just wanted to point out that OP, as per his own comment, is not after the fastest approach, which your answer seems to be mostly about.

Comment: Re-read the title and see the mention of "better". Once better is defined, then approaches should be measured rather than relying on big-O. Not gratuitous or derogatory; *measured*.