# How to add each element in list to another element of same list in less time?

Tags: python-3.x, list, time-complexity, complexity-theory, space-complexity

```
Input : l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
Output :     [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11]
```

To find the maximum sum of each pair of all elements in a list.
In general, i have to add each element in list to another element (not to itself).
Below is the code what i tried. I know this is complexity of `(n^2)`

Any better way to reduce complexity (can be both time and space) ?

Any better approach (may be with some modules or with just single for loop) ?

`list l1` need not to be in `sorted`.

```
l2=[]
l3=[]
for i in range(len(l1)):
   for j in range(len(l1)):
      if i!=j:
         l2.append(l1[i]+l1[j])
   l3.append(max(l2))
   l2.clear()



print(l3)
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11]
```

**Update:**
Submitted this solution in hackerrank, but it fails for few cases.
Reason for failure is `TimeLimitExceed` (TLE). I assume, it's failing because of large numbers.

```
**Constraints:**
n = size_of_list

1<= n <= 4*10^4
1<= l1[i] <= 1024
1<= i <= n
1<= j <= n
j != i
```

Is it because of `time-complexity`, failing to handle these scenarios in above snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, we can use sorting to our advantage. The Python sorting method, `sorted`, operates in `O(n log n)` time. (See this question: [What is the complexity of this python sort method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434490/what-is-the-complexity-of-this-python-sort-method))

Once our numbers are sorted, the maximum sums are trivial. The maximum for a number is simply that number added to the last element in the sorted list or, if the number is the maximum element, the second to last element. Rewriting your code we could obtain:

```py
l3 = []
l1 = sorted(l1)

for i in range(len(l1)):
    if i + 1 == len(l1):
        l3.append(l1[i] + l1[i - 1])
    else:
        l3.append(l1[i] + l1[-1])

print(l3)
```

I hope this helps. Let me know if I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: Append takes only one argument. Please check it.

Comment: @StackGuru, you are correct. I meant to add the two elements. My bad!

Comment: No Problem, i got your approach. Good one. But list can't be in sorted order. Thanks for that, updating my question.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
l2=[]
for i in range(len(l1)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(l1)):
            l2.append(l1[i]+l1[j])
l3=set(l2)
l2=list(l3)
print(l2)
```

output:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Sorting your list before processing it also helps.
Let me know if i have made any mistake.

Comment: Output doesn't match. And also, you have to add an element with all other elements (not to itself. Say, it can't be 1+1, 2+2,3+3 etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `O(n)`.

The basic idea is to get the indices of the maximum element and the second maximum element in the list. Then for each element in the list, append the element + max_element, **if the element is not the max_element**. Otherwise, append the max_element + second_max_element.

I used the get_first_second_max_index to get the indices of the maximum element and the second maximum element because there might be identical elements in the list.

The code should look like this:

```
def get_first_second_max_index(nums):
    if len(nums) < 2:
        return None, None

    first_max_index = 0 if nums[0] > nums[1] else 1
    second_max_index = 0 if nums[0] <= nums[1] else 1

    for index in range(2, len(nums)):
        if nums[index] > nums[first_max_index]:
            first_max_index, second_max_index = index, first_max_index
        elif nums[index] > nums[second_max_index]:
            second_max_index = index

    return (first_max_index, second_max_index)


def max_sum_pair(nums):
    res = []
    if len(nums) >= 2:
        first_max_index, second_max_index = get_first_second_max_index(nums)

        for index in range(len(nums)):
            if index == first_max_index:
                res.append(nums[index] + nums[second_max_index])
            else:
                res.append(nums[index] + nums[first_max_index])

    return res

nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
res = max_sum_pair(nums)
print(res)
```