# Groupby a list of dicts with multiple keys doesn't work even if I use sorted before

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, itertools-groupby

I have a list of dictionaries like that :

```
a = [
    {'user_id':'111','clean_label':'VIR SEPA'},
    {'user_id':'112','clean_label':'VIR SEPA'},
    {'user_id':'111','clean_label':'VIR SEPA'},
]
```

and I want that :

```
a = [
    [
        {'user_id':'111','clean_label':'VIR SEPA'},
        {'user_id':'111','clean_label':'VIR SEPA'}
    ],
    [
        {'user_id':'112','clean_label':'VIR SEPA'}
    ]
]
```

I tried with sorted and groupby from itertools like that :

```
sorted(a,key=lambda x: (x['user_id'],x['clean_label']))
[ [tr for tr in tr_per_user_id_clean_label] for key, tr_per_user_id_clean_label in itertools.groupby(a, key=lambda x: (x['user_id'], x['clean_label'])) ]
```

but I get that :

```
[[{'user_id': '111', 'clean_label': 'VIR SEPA'}],
 [{'user_id': '112', 'clean_label': 'VIR SEPA'}],
 [{'user_id': '111', 'clean_label': 'VIR SEPA'}]]
```

Can someone help me ??

*Edit : when I sort a :

```
[{'user_id': '111', 'clean_label': 'VIR SEPA'},
 {'user_id': '111', 'clean_label': 'VIR SEPA'},
 {'user_id': '112', 'clean_label': 'VIR SEPA'}]
```

Comment: FWIW, `'user_id'` are strings which are not going to be sorted the way you expect

Comment: Anyway, `sorted` is not in-place. You need to assign it to a variable to be able to use the sorted list

Comment: `[list(g) for _, g in groupby(sorted(a, key=itemgetter('user_id')), itemgetter('user_id'))]`

Comment: Oh yes I forgot too many times to assign sorry

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.groupby` is not really the ideal tool for this.

You can achieve your goal with O(n) complexity using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) (vs O(n log n) with `groupby` as you need to sort):

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)

for d in a:
    dd[(d['user_id'], d['clean_label'])].append(d)
    
out = list(dd.values())
```

alternative with `setdefault`:

```
dd = {}

for d in a:
    dd.setdefault((d['user_id'], d['clean_label']), []).append(d)
    
out = list(dd.values())
```

output:

```
[[{'user_id': '111', 'clean_label': 'VIR SEPA'},
  {'user_id': '111', 'clean_label': 'VIR SEPA'}],
 [{'user_id': '112', 'clean_label': 'VIR SEPA'}]]
```

If the output needs to be sorted by user_id:

```
out = sorted(dd.values(),
             key=lambda x: (int(x[0]['user_id']), int(x[0]['clean_label'])))
```

Comment: @DeepSpace why? I don't think sorting was a requirement for the data only because OP wanted to use `groupby`. And if you need to sort it might be more efficient to sort the aggregated output as there are less values to handle (something like `sorted(out, key=lambda x: int(x[0]['user_id']))`) ;)

Comment: I suppose you are correct

Comment: and if I want to use multiple keys ?

Comment: then use a tuple as key of the intermediate dictionary

Comment: @Quxntin You can use the tuple as a key

Comment: apparently someone didn't like my answer… not sure why

Comment: OP specified multiple sort keys and multiple group keys, even though it doesn't affect the output. So it should be `dd[d['user_id'], d['clean_label']].append(d)`, etc. (I didn't downvote though.)

Comment: @wjandrea I'll update but it doesn't change the logic at all

Comment: Good detailed answer, +1

Comment: Remark: [sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434490/what-is-the-complexity-of-the-sorted-function) is  O(n log n)

Comment: @cards yes, this is what I wrote in the answer ;)

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought it was referred to `groupby` (which I don't know)

Comment: No sorry, I meant `sort`, `groupby` should be O(n) I guess

Answer (score 1):

`sorted()` returns a new list and does not change the order of the existing list. You want either `a.sort()` or `groupby(sorted(a, key=...), key=...)`.

Although, why bother sorting at all? You could use a dict as an accumulator, like in [mozway's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72548345/4518341).

Comment: Or `b = sorted(...)` and `groupby(b, ...)`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Eh? That's equivalent to option 2, and I don't see any reason to keep an extra copy of the data around.

Comment: Yeah I see what mozway's did, sometimes I'm just to focus on 1 idea, but mozway's had a better idea than me to get that

Comment: Yes, it is basically option #2. Depending on line length, it might make sense to break out a separate variable rather than a long nested expression on a single line.