# How to conditionally sort a list in python with respect to two lists

Tags: python, list, sorting

Is there a simple way to sort a list X in python using two other lists Y,Z like so?

before sorting:

```
X = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
Y = [ 10,   1,   2,   16 ] #positive list
Z = [  5,  6,   7,  10 ] #negative list
```

creating list W to assist with understanding

```
W = [  5,  -5,  -5,  6 ] # create new list total (Y-Z) positive - negative values.
```

This is what I have done so far, sorted X according to W the total of Y,Z (Y-Z) in descending

- Sort X based on W (total) in descending order

```
W, X = zip(*sorted(zip(W, X),reverse=True))
X = ["d", "a", "b", "c"]
W = [  6,  5,  -5,  -5 ]
```

What I would like to do further is conditionally sort
if values of W are equal, I'd like to sort based on highest value in list Y, lowest value in list Z and choosing the maximum.

```
X = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
Y = [ 10,   1,   2,   16 ] #positive list
Z = [  5,  6,   7,  10 ] #negative list
W = [  5,  -5,  -5,  6 ] # create new list total (Y-Z) positive - negative values.
```

here, indexes 1,2 are tied in W because W[1]==W[2]=-5
so we compare k1=max(Y[1],Y[2])=max(1,2)=2 and k2=min(Z[1],Z[2])=min(6,7)=6

- since k2>k1, we prioritize ordering of X based on Z
- if k1>k2 we should prioritize ordering of X based on Y.
  final result must be,

```
X = ["d", "a", "b", "c"]
```

How could we do this as simple as possible even for huge lists with n number of same values in the list W?

Comment: You can make use of [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) which python uses to compare sequences *(Read: [5.8. Comparing Sequences and Other Types](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types))* and sort `X` in one line: `sorted(enumerate(X), reverse=True, key=lambda x: (Y[x[0]] - Z[x[0]], -Z[x[0]], Y[x[0]]))`. Just take second element from each pair and job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here from my point of view the actual right answer which tests for the condition according to which list the sub-sorting in case W-values are the same should be done.

To accomplish the sub-sorting W-values are now extended to a tuple with an index of item in X. After sorting the extended W the `itertools.groupby()` is used to put together items with same W-value and the indices of items in X are used to find the max-value in Y and min-value in Z required to decide about the key to sub-sorting in case of same W-values. Then the indices are further used to put the right items of X together in fully sorted order.

Here the code which accomplishes this:

```
X    = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
Y    = [10 ,  2,   1 , 16 ] # positive list
Z    = [ 5 ,  7,   6 , 10 ] # negative list
Wsorted = sorted([ (Y[i]-Z[i], i) for i in range(len(X)) ])
Xsorted = []
import itertools
for _, g in itertools.groupby(Wsorted, lambda w: w[0]):
    lg = list(g)
    if len(lg) == 1:
        Xsorted += X[lg[0][1]]
    else:
        maxY = max([Y[i] for _,i in lg])
        minZ = min([Z[i] for _,i in lg])
        if maxY  > minZ: lg.sort(key=lambda lgitem: Y[lgitem[1]])
        if maxY  < minZ: lg.sort(key=lambda lgitem: Z[lgitem[1]])
        if maxY == minZ: pass # no preferred sub-sorting
        Xsorted += [ X[lgitem[1]] for lgitem in lg ]
Xsorted.reverse()
print(f'{Xsorted=}') # gives: Xsorted=['d', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

*The above code covers a general case of sorting condition based on comparison of maximum of values in Y and minimum of values in Z for same W-values to decide about sub-sorting according to Y or to Z.*

The general case **does not take into consideration that when W values are Y values minus Z values it doesn't actually matter for the sub-sorting after which, Y or Z values, the sub-sorting has to be done.**

It doesn't actually matter as the order of Y values for same W values is always the same as the order of Z values because of the equal difference.

So a search for a maximum value in Y and minimum value in Z is not necessary in this special case of W and the sorting can be made much easier just using only Y values *( or Z values which gives same result )* for the sub-sorting.

Below the one liner performing such a sort for the case of the simple W being the difference between Y and Z values:

```
Xsorted = [ X[i] for i in sorted( 
    list(range(len(X))),key=lambda i: (Y[i]-Z[i],Y[i]),reverse=True)]
print(Xsorted) # gives ['d', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Thanks, could you explain how this is different from 
```data = list(zip(X, Y, Z))

def sort_criteria(x):
    return x[1] - x[2], max(x[1], -x[2])```

Comment: Most apparent difference is that when Y and Z have only positive values sub-sorting by `max(x[1], -x{2])` will always be done using only Y values `(==x[1])` as they 'win' against Z values turned to be negative `(==-x[2])` by the minus sign, what does not make any sense to me. The other is that there is no check for a minimum values in Z against maximum values in Y at all, as a key function does not consider ranges of indices with same W-value working only with the current index to data (i.e. to X, Y, Z) to decide about a second value next to W-value for sub-sorting.

Comment: See my updated answer providing a one-liner for sorting X in the special case of W being a difference between Y and Z.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand the details of your sort logic because I get a different result, but the general idea is to define your sort criteria clearly as a function and then pass it to sort on your data as a list of tuples.

```
X = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
Y = [ 10,   1,   2,   16 ] #positive list
Z = [  5,  6,   7,  10 ] #negative list

data = list(zip(X, Y, Z))

def sort_criteria(x):
    return x[1] - x[2], max(x[1], -x[2])

data.sort(key=sort_criteria)
print(data)
result = [item[0] for item in data]
```

```
[('b', 1, 6), ('c', 2, 7), ('a', 10, 5), ('d', 16, 10)]
```

Comment: thank you so much, this is what I wanted to achieve! also, what would the time complexity of this be?

Comment: I don't know but there is a post about time complexity here: [What is the complexity of the sorted() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14434490/1609514)

Comment: @GargeeSuresh well, it's a sorting algorithm, and CPython uses Timsort, which ahs worst-case O(N*logN) since it is basically a (highly optimized, adaptive) merge sort.

Comment: @GargeeSuresh sorry to say that, but it appears to me that the answer, even if accepted,  is not working as you requested it in your question. It doesn't sort according to Y or to Z depending on the comparison of the maximum of Y with the minimum of Z for all the items with same W value. I assume that it isn't possible to sort X in one run with one key function, because you have first to group all of the items in Y and Z with same W value and then decide which one, Y or Z, will be used for sorting X where W values are the same.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3 you could use `functools.cmp_to_key` to sort a list based on a custom comparator. In a custom corporator you could implement whatever complex logic you may think of.

```py
def comparator(item1, item2):
    # compares two tuples item1=(x1,y1,z1) and item2=(x2,y2,z2)
    # returns:
    #     1 if item1 > item2, 
    #    -1 if item1 < item2, 
    #     0 if item1 = item2
    if (item1[1] - item1[2]) > (item2[1] - item2[2]): # W[1] > W[2]
        return 1
    elif (item1[1] - item1[2]) < (item2[1] - item2[2]):
        return -1
    
    if min(item1[2], item2[2]) > max(item1[1], item2[1]): # k2 > k1
        if item1[2] < item2[2]:
            return 1
        elif item1[2] > item2[2]:
            return -1
        else: # k2 > k1 but z2 = z1
            if item1[1] > item2[1]:
                return 1
            elif item1[1] < item2[1]:
                return -1
            else:
                return 0
    elif min(item1[2], item2[2]) > max(item1[1], item2[1]): # k1 > k2
        if item1[1] > item1[2]:
            return 1
        elif item1[2] < item2[1]:
            return -1
        else: # k1 > k2 but y1 = y2
            if item1[2] < item2[2]:
                return 1
            elif item1[2] > item2[2]:
                return -1
            else:
                return 0
    else: # k1 = k2
        if item1[2] < item2[2]: # Z1 < Z2
            return 1
        elif item1[2] > item2[2]:
            return -1
        elif item1[1] > item2[1]: # Z1 = Z2, Y1 > Y2
            return 1
        elif item1[1] < item2[1]:
            return -1
        else:
            return 0
```

Now you could use this comparator as

```py
from functools import cmp_to_key
sorted(zip(X,Y,Z), key=cmp_to_key(comparator), reverse=True)
```

This would return

```
[('d', 16, 10), ('a', 10, 5), ('b', 1, 6), ('c', 2, 7)]
```